# Neo4j Add/update properties if node exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to be able to `update/enlarge` my Neo4j database by uploading a newer version of that database OR part of that database.

Of what I've found I can use `MERGE` to `add` new nodes just if they don't already exists. But in that process, how do I in a slimmed way `add` new properties to that existing node if they don't exist?

I e, if I have a node `'John' of 'Age:34' and 'Hair:brown'` and upload `'John'/'Age:34'/'Coat:Yellow'` - how do I get `'John'/'Age:34'/'Hair:brown'/'Coat:Yellow'`.

Answer (score 35):

You could merge the node on **John** (or the primary identifying attribute).  And then set the properties after the successful merge.

You could set them all at once with a map for all attributes

```
MERGE (n:Node {name: 'John'})
SET n = {name: 'John', age: 34, coat: 'Yellow', hair: 'Brown'}
RETURN n
```

If you just wanted to replace the attributes **age** and **coat**, you could do this instead.

```
MERGE (n:Node {name: 'John'})
SET n.age = 34, n.coat = 'Yellow'
RETURN n
```

Or you could add it as a map too

```
MERGE (n:Node {name: 'John'})
SET n += {age: 34, coat: 'Yellow'}
RETURN n
```

Comment: thanks alot! looks promising:) just to clarify: if I set a property to a node that already has that property, can it get two? can John has two ages, both of 34? if I set 5 properties to a node, does it become all that node's properties, i e does the 'other' properties get deleted?

Comment: In the attributes will be replaced with what you provide. In the first example the entire entry will be replaced by the attribute/value pairs in the map.  In the subsequent example only those attributes specified will be touched; note the use of the compound assignment operator (`+=`) in the third example.  You will not end up with two ages if you set an age and one already exists.  To achieve that you would have to do a little more fiddling first.

Comment: How can merge with multiples name?

Answer (score 2):

MERGE guarantees that a node will exist afterwards (either matched or created). If you don't want to create the node, you need to use MATCH instead. (Since you say "if node exists", that implies it shouldn't be created)

The simplest way is

```
MATCH (n{id:{uuid}) SET n.prop=true
```

If the match fails, their will be nothing to do the SET against.

Assuming that you would like to still have rows after; (for a more complex query) You can just make the match optional

```
...
OPTIONAL MATCH (n{id:{uuid}) SET n.prop=true
```

Again, if the match fails, n will be null, and the SET will do nothing

Answer (score -1):

How to add multiple properties to already existed node

```
#payload={"query" : 
      " MATCH (t:TvSeries{id:{id})SET t.next_episode_to_air_air_date:
{next_episode_to_air_air_date},next_episode_to_air_episode_number:
{next_episode_to_air_episode_number},next_episode_to_air_id:
{next_episode_to_air_id},next_episode_to_air_name:
{next_episode_to_air_name},next_episode_to_air_overview:
{next_episode_to_air_overview},next_episode_to_air_production_code:
{next_episode_to_air_production_code},next_episode_to_air_season_number:
{next_episode_to_air_season_number},next_episode_to_air_show_id_id:
{next_episode_to_air_show_id},next_episode_to_air_still_path: 
{next_episode_to_air_still_path},next_episode_to_air_vote_average: 
{next_episode_to_air_vote_average},next_episode_to_air_vote_count: 
{next_episode_to_air_vote_count}RETURN t"}

        payload['params'] = params
        response_json = callNeo4j(payload, headers)
```