# Rails Neo4j How to add new field in existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

```
class Invitation
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :email
end
```

This is Neo node Invitation node I can see it in the graph database.
 - If I add some new field in it, for existing nodes it will not reflect in the graph database
 - If I create a new node I can see it in graph database

So the question is if I have to add one field suppose

`property :valid, type: Boolean, default: true`

How can I add this so that I can see it in existing nodes in graph database???, same like we do in active record migrations

I have added field in Node

`property :vish, type: Boolean, default: true`

So when query

`Invitation.where(vish: true).count` ==> result 0

If I add new node Invitation.create(email: 'urvishh@gmail.com')

Then run query

`Invitation.where(vish: true).count` ==> result 1

This is exact issue I am getting

Comment: I think this is duplicated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255540/neo4j-add-update-properties-if-node-exists

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos if I get the answer in context of rails purely doing it wil wrapper

Comment: Yeah well the issue is the same, neo4j doesn't handle migrations, you don't need to add something over all the nodes. I didn't read the `property`method code, but I'm sure it will do something like: `value.present? value : default_value`

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos yes I also belive that neo4j doesn't handle migrations , But I have added exact issue why I am thinking of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer will be **No**: there is no way to **Search** for undeclared property values in persisted nodes.

**Edited:**

They added a Migration like behaviour for the gem that might fit your current needs.

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Migrations.html

**Discovery answer:**

Nodes should be considered as documents that stores properties inside them. What we are dealing here is with an implementation of the Cypher Query and the `Neo4j::ActiveNode` that not only ignores the default values for properties.

This could be easily tested:

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name, type: String
  property :email, type: String, default: 'example@example.com'
end
```

Then create two nodes:

```
User.create(name: 'John', email: 'john@cena.com'
User.create(name: 'John')
```

We try to search for undeclared property **values**:

```
> User.where(title: 'Mr')
=> #<QueryProxy  CYPHER: "MATCH (result_user:`User`) WHERE (result_user.title = {result_user_title})">
```

We effectively call `Cyper` and get results, this means that the property declaration in model is not used at all in the `Neo4j::ActiveNode#where`

It means is only used to set and get properties, but ignored by the finders.

There might be workarounds, that are actually missing implementations in the Neo4j gem:

You can search by array of values in the Cyper connector, but is not parsing properly the values:

```
User.where(another_field: nil).count
CYPHER 39ms MATCH (result_user:`User`) WHERE (result_user.another_field IS NULL) RETURN count(result_user) AS result_user
=> 100
User.where(another_field: ['Something', nil]).count
 CYPHER 12ms MATCH (result_user:`User`) WHERE (result_user.another_field IN {result_user_another_field}) RETURN count(result_user) AS result_user | {:result_user_another_field=>["Something", nil]}
=> 0
```

As you can see in the last query, `nil` is passed literally. So you can't do this.

I've opened an [Issue](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1327) in the repository in your behalf, and linked this question in order to get a solution.

Comment: what about this https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Migrations

Comment: As stated in my answer, you just need to declare the properties in the model, you don't need migrations to add properties to nodes: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.x/Properties.html#undeclared-properties

Comment: Yes I did the same But the query goes wrong as previous records is not picking up value default: true.............. I have added the situation in the question, Even if I open neo4j web UI then I can not see the new field in the node, I see if brand new object is created

Comment: What about add the property and run: `Model.update_all(:property, default_value)`

Comment: sorry for delay... Yes update_all I am doing the same thing for now, But it seem like a spoof what do you thing?

Comment: Did you find a better solution? I can expend some time and build a local dev  to try it.

Comment: No Still I didn't get better solution :(

Comment: Downloaded and installedo neo4j, created a sample node with two fields, and then used: `property :another_field, default: "something"` retrieved the user from the database, and the default was coming. So my answer was right. Neo4j 3.0.7, rails 5, ruby 2.3.

Comment: Try this Modal_name.where(another_field: "something").count, you will get zero results, and before adding this field you should create some nodes..Defualt always comes if we add this in modal for existing records as well, but query does not include these default when making cypher query.......as it happens in realtional databse when we add some field with defaut value , all field will get these values after running migration

Comment: Updated the answer after researching and testing the issue, and confirming that this is a major milestone in the gem.

Comment: Can you please add the supported neo4j version needed to use these migrations that would be helpful

Comment: v8.0.0.rc.4 ->
https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1327#issuecomment-266307838