# Neo4j add/update property ONLY if node exists. If not then do nothing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It's extiension of question [Neo4j Add/update properties if node exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255540/neo4j-add-update-properties-if-node-exists)
There's answer how to MERGE (create or update) node:

> You could set them all at once with a map for all attributes

`merge (n:Node {name: 'John'})
set n = {name: 'John', age: 34, coat: 'Yellow', hair: 'Brown'}
return n`

> If you just wanted to replace the attributes age and coat, you could do this instead.

`merge (n:Node {name: 'John'})
set n.age = 34, n.coat = 'Yellow'
return n`

> Or you could add it as a map too

`merge (n:Node {name: 'John'})
set n += {age: 34, coat: 'Yellow'}
return n`

Can anyone tell how to UPDATE node ONLY if it exists, but do nothing if node doesn't exists.

Comment: MERGE guarantees that a node will exist afterwards (either matched or created). If you don't want to create the node, you need to use MATCH instead.

Comment: Actually, this looks like the same question as before, just a little clearer, and I think the old question misunderstood how MERGE works. What is the difference between what you asked here vs there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
MATCH (n{id:{uuid}) SET n.prop=true
```

If the match fails, their will be nothing to do the SET against.

Assuming that you would like to still have rows after; (so you can still also return data for a more complex query) You can just make the match optional

```
...
OPTIONAL MATCH (n{id:{uuid}) SET n.prop=true
```

Again, if the match fails, n will be null, and the SET will do nothing

Comment: Thank you! It's clear now about updating and it actually does what i wanted. And can you explain, what  you mean saying "Assuming that you would like to still have rows after"?

Comment: @ArtemS. If you do `MATCH (a{id:1}) MATCH (b{id2})` If one of the nodes does not exist, the Cypher will "drop" all rows (because no row could meet the criteria). If you make the second one OPTIONAL, than Cypher will make that value null instead of dropping the whole row from its match set. So if you do `RETURN *` at the end of the Cypher, it is the difference between getting 1 row or 0 rows back (in this example)